# Wordpress getblocks in editor is returning an error: ( 'core/editor' ).getBlocks` is deprecated

Tags: wordpress, iis, woocommerce, php-7

I'm using WordPress 5.7.2 (on Windows IIS).

I'm trying to use the block editor to add a list of newest products, best selling or featured products - when I do I get the error:

```
Error loading block: <p>There has been a critical error on this website.</p><p>
<a href="https://wordpress.org/support/article/faq-troubleshooting/">
Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress.</a></p>
```

[image: Screenshot of error in block editor]

I can use the block editor to add paragraphs, social icons etc, just not lists.

I looked in developer tools, and the errors are shown in the screenshot:

```
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.3.2
deprecated.min.js?ver=be1d4376501c21d85ba98dd28ca2d7ea:2 wp.editor.withColors is deprecated. 
Please use wp.blockEditor.withColors instead.
c @ deprecated.min.js?ver=be1d4376501c21d85ba98dd28ca2d7ea:2
post-new.php:2699 `woocommerce_shared_settings` filter in Blocks is deprecated. See https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gutenberg-products-block/blob/trunk/docs/contributors/block-assets.md
```

(anonymous) @ post-new.php:2699
edit-post.min.js?ver=a3b1db92ec26fb13459a7d6f527e1f90:7
Your browser is using Quirks Mode.

etc

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getBlocks` is deprecated. Please use `wp.data.select( 'core/block-editor' ).getBlocks` instead
```

Any ideas what may be causing this?  All my plugins (WooCommerce etc) are on the latest versions - it just seems to be the bock editor that is at fault.

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer - following the age old advice - disable one plug-in at a time.

For me, the issue was with **Code Snippets - Version 2.14.1**

The actual plugin is great, and works as it should - however, for each "snippet" you can set it to run only on the front-end, or everywhere (including when you're logged in as admin).

Turning the snippets to only work on the front-end, stopped this issue altogether.

No more errors.

I hope this helps anyone else.

Thanks, Mark